# Apache - Apache2 Debian Default Page instead of my website

Tags: apache, debian, apache2

I have an Apache 2 on Debian and am a beginner (newbie).
When accessing to my webserver in the web brower, I get the Apache default welcome page :

[image]

Instead of this page (located in var/www/html), I try to make my real website displayed (var/www/mywebsite.com/). Below is the tree on my server :

```
---- etc
-------- apache2
------------ sites-enabled
---------------- mywebsite.com.vhost -> etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com.vhost
------------ sites-available
---------------- mywebsite.com.vhost

---- var
-------- www
------------ mywebsite.com
---------------- web
-------------------- css/
-------------------- js/
-------------------- img/
-------------------- error/
-------------------- index.html
-------------------- robots.txt
```

My .vhost file is well configurated :

```
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
```

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com

ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com

ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mywebsite.com/error.log

Alias /error/ "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/"
ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html


<Directory /var/www/mywebsite.com/web>

    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted.

</Directory>
```

.. and I made a restart Apache. No success ! The Apache default page is still here. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

To Delete index.html

Your `index.html` located at /var/www/html

1. `cd /var/www/html`
2. `sudo chown -R` whoami `/var/www/html`
3. `rm index.html`
4. `ls`

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` located at `/var/www/mywebsite.com/web`, I guess this is the website root folder? Try this config:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com/web
```

Comment: Hello Ben, same result. I discovered that the only *.conf file loaded by Apache was etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The only *.conf file loaded by Apache was etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf, then I worked on this file to get my issue solved.

Hope that will help someone in the future !

Answer (score 0):

just remove these two files index.html and index.nginx-debian.html from this path /var/www/html ....Good

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove anything. You could simply update the index.html with new html/css/js content. Keep in mind changes will not reflect until you restart your Debian. There is an option to see the update instantly but it is another command.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what is the option for "update instantly"?

Comment: It is an option added within apache2 installation where updates you make to php http css etc reflect instantly without having to restart your machine. I can look into it further if you are interested. I saw this on debian btw, can't say on other linux installations.
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-2-reload-httpd-config-file-unix-linux-command/